# Question_ regarding Active Directory of remote server

Tags: active-directory

I am new to Active Directory and still learning some of the concepts.

The code below shows connecting to AD on my local machine and this code works properly

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=testing1,CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com");
DirectoryEntryConfiguration entryConfiguration = entry.Options;

Console.WriteLine("Server: " + entryConfiguration.GetCurrentServerName());
Console.WriteLine("Page Size: " + entryConfiguration.PageSize.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Password Encoding: " + entryConfiguration.PasswordEncoding.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Password Port: " + entryConfiguration.PasswordPort.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Referral: " + entryConfiguration.Referral.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Security Masks: " + entryConfiguration.SecurityMasks.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Is Mutually Authenticated: " + entryConfiguration.IsMutuallyAuthenticated().ToString());
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Here is my problem: when I replace `mydomain` in the LDAP path of another machine it gives me an error

```
LDAP://CN=testing1,CN=Users,DC=XXXX,DC=com
```

gives me this error

> *System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException was unhandled
>   Message=A referral was returned from the server.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was basically a teething error

Instead of this:

```
LDAP://CN=testing1,CN=Users,DC=XXXX,DC=com
```

I should have written

```
LDAP://XXX.com/CN=testing1,CN=Users,DC=XXXX,DC=com
```